# How to Uncheck all celltemplate checked checkboxes in angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

This is my ui-grid

```
 $scope.gridOptions = {
      columnDefs: [
        { name: 'name'},
        { name: 'view', cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="fieldView" ng-checked="checked" ng-init="checked=row.entity.required" ng-disabled="checked" ng-click="grid.appScope.view(fieldView,row.entity);getExternalScopes().showMe(row.entity.required)">', enableSorting: false, enableColumnMenu: false },
        { name: 'edit', cellTemplate: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="fieldEdit" ng-checked="checked" ng-init="checked=row.entity.required" ng-disabled="checked" ng-click="grid.appScope.edit(fieldEdit,row.entity);getExternalScopes().showMe(row.entity.required)">', enableSorting: false, enableColumnMenu: false }
       ]
  };
```

In the above UI-grid contains 3 columns.view and edit column contains checkboxes,I want to uncheck all checked checkboxes in UI-grid,because first I render some data and check checkboxes then I render another data from api.but in this case whatever first time check the checkboxes those are not clear at the time second time data rendering to UI-grid.

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer.
$scope.gridOptions.data=[];